# Some layout questions about Qgis2web

Tags: qgis2web

i just tried the plugin Qgis2web.
The result looks already very nice

But to optimize to lay out , i have some questions.

How is it possible to display a title on the map? 
How is it possible to display a logo and the name of your organisation in the right corner?

I changed already the code for the lay out in the pop up content but how is it possible to create a white space  between 'voornaam' and achternaam'.

And a last little thing: If i haven't a value in the variable 'National_1'it display 'null' instead of a white space..

var popupContent = 'Naam' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['voornaam'])) +
             Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Achternaam'])) + 
            'Geboortedatum' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Geboorteda'])) + 
            'Nationaliteit' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Nationalit'])) + 
             Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['National_1'])) +
             'Positie' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['Positie']))
             '';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Give your QGIS project a title, and it will appear as a title on Leaflet exports, though not OpenLayers3 maps. You can then edit the Leaflet code to add in a logo.

I'm not sure how you have created that popup content - it's normally a table - so I'm not sure how to help with your last issue. You can of course add in `+ ' '` manually.

I'll look into the null issue and report back.

Comment: Already thanks a lot, i would try it tomorrow.

For the null, i think it's something the default. Because i used 'MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE' to create the tables. I would try with one other default. i let you know of it worked!

Comment: The null issue is a recent reversion, I'm pretty sure. I've refactored a lot of the Leaflet export code in the last week or two, so it probably crept in then. I'll look into it.

Comment: I cannot now recreate the null issue. Can you share your layer and list your settings?